# Wrapping form elements in common div tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Is there  a better way to do what I am doing, one that is more rails standards then what I am attempting?:

```
<%= form_for @project, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :project_title %>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.text_field :project_title %>
    </div>
    <div class='control-group'>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Some part of me thinks this is wrong. So I am wondering what standards are? I am have been reading [rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Take a look to [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#twitter-bootstrap) support.